# Move an existing RAID 5 array from Ubuntu to Gentoo

Tags: raid, mdadm, gentoo, md

I have a 64-bit Ubuntu machine with a 4-disk RAID 5 using software raid (md). I've been able to boot an Ubuntu LiveCD and recognize the array with a simple `mdadm -A /dev/md0`. It was easy to mount after that and nothing had to rebuild.

I'm installing Gentoo on this box now (multi-boot, non-RAID root partition) and I have md auto-detect turned on in the kernel. When I boot Gentoo I get: "invalid superblock magic on sdd" for each of the drives in the array. I boot back to Ubuntu and they mount no problem.

I tried copying the mdadm.conf that works in Ubuntu to Gentoo, and then ran `mdadm -A /dev/md0` but it reports that there is no array named md0.

I don't want to lose data (obviously) and I don't want to have to let the RAID rebuild every time I switch between OSes. Any help is appreciated.

Both are using mdadm 3.1.4

Both are running 64-bit kernels.

`mdadm -D /dev/md0` from Ubuntu yields:  http://pastebin.com/5gj2QNkV

UPDATE: After rebooting I noticed that it still complains about invalid blocks, but `cat /proc/mdstat` shows an inactive `/dev/md127` with the same disks as my raid. I want to mount it but I don't want to get stuck waiting for a rebuild or destroying it inadvertently. `mdadm -D /dev/md127`
Here is pastebin of `mdadm -D /dev/md127` on gentoo: http://pastebin.com/gDCWn0Rn

UPDATE II:

dmesg output about 'invalid raid superblocks' http://paste.ubuntu.com/885471/

`fdisk -l` from Ubuntu, /dev/md0 does not have any partitions but I do have it mounted and accessible: http://paste.ubuntu.com/885475/

Comment: Are you using partitions or full disks for array members?

Comment: What are your `mdadm` version numbers? Is your Gentoo install 64-bit? Output of `mdadm -D /dev/md0`?

Comment: Full disks for array members. Both are 64-bit. I'll have to check on versions.
`mdadm -D /dev/md0` from Ubuntu: http://pastebin.com/5gj2QNkV

Comment: You could post more context (log) for the "invalid superblock magic" since that could either be the raid superblock or somehow a filesystem superblock.

Comment: I've added relevant `dmesg` and `fdisk` output.

Comment: Kernel raid auto-detection doesn't work for >=1.0 superblocks. Those messages are harmless and you should not enable it.

Comment: Would recompiling with auto-detection disabled solve my problem? Or is it just a harmless red-herring?

Comment: I got it working. I disabled auto-detection and noticed that I hadn't added support for RAID 5. Ended up being much simpler than I thought. Mark, I said the bounty would be given for help, not necessarily a direct answer; if you submit an actual answer I will select it and give you the bounty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The renaming of software raid devices is something unproblematic (here from md0 to md127). I've seen this over the last years and you shouldn't worry about it.

But your were totally right to ask about the auto-assembly warnings. Here, the devil lies in the details. In dmesg you see it's trying to find mdadm **0.90c** superblocks (the old ones). It fails and it does naturally fail, **because your volume is formatted using version 1.2 metadata.** No problem here too.

See **man 8 mdadm** about which metadata format you have as default on Ubuntu and Gentoo. I would guess even if it's not in the manpages, that you run different kernel configs concerning soft raid (see "Multiple Devices" in make menuconfig).

So, in my experience of around eight years with mdadm/soft raid with linux, **you are good to go**. No reason to worry, besides getting a more current kernel :-)

EDIT: Also, dont worry about your array being corrupt. You can clearly see from your status pastes, that its just fine, as one would expect.

Do you have further questions on the matter?

Answer (score 1):

Re-posted:

> Kernel raid auto-detection doesn't work for >=1.0 superblocks. Those
>   messages are harmless and you should not enable it.